# Background Image only showing in h2 heading but not whole row/column

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make my background image fit the whole row/column but am unable to split up the text from the h3 heading and body text. I'm also not sure why my image is cropped and isn't fitting the same width as the rest of my rows.

(I'm very very new to HTML/CSS)

[My current design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zy7xM.png)

[My desired Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdiuy.png)

This is my current HTML/CSS for this section:

```css
 h3.gramps-image {
      background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/H7Y0z8K/Blackandwhitegramps.jpg");
      background-color: #00000; 
      background-size: cover; 
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat; 
      position: relative;  
}
```

```html
HTML 

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm">
            <h3 class= "gramps-image"> Featured Destination: Brambuk (Grampians) Edible Bushfood Track <br>Native edible plants have fed humans for hundreds of years. On this 8km track in the heart of the Brambuk (Grampians), you can learn about the importance of Bushfood with a downloadable guide created in collaboration with Jadawadjali and Djab Wurrung peoples. 
            </h3>
        </div> 
    </div>
```

or a link to the [codepen](http://%20https://codepen.io/alicebutcher/pen/wvedNWe)

Comment: You should change your CSS rule to match the html element you wish the background to be a part of. I.E. if you want the div with the class row to have this background image, give it a unique identifier and set the background css rule to it.

Comment: I don't really understand sorry @tomerpacific, as in

'<div class="gramps-image" "row">'

Comment: You have typo in the attribute background-color (missing a c). Also, I do not understand what you want to achieve. Can you edit your question and explain it better?

Comment: @butchal After seeing your desired design image, I have made some modification in the code to achieve the same. You can check here: https://codepen.io/Hitesh_Vadher/pen/rNwmEvL?editors=1100, although I don't understand what specifically you want to achieve through your question.

Comment: That change you made is what I was trying to do! Sorry I'm dyslexic so trying to explain was a little tricky. I'm just struggling to wrap my head around rules/classes once created and where to put them in my HTML

Answer (score 1):

Its because the row and columns have margin and padding.  This will give you the desired look.

```css
h3.gramps-image {
      background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/H7Y0z8K/Blackandwhitegramps.jpg");
      bakground-color: #00000; 
      background-size: cover; 
      background-position: centre;
      background-repeat: no-repeat; 
      position: relative; 
      
    }
    
    body {
      margin:0;
      }
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row p-0 m-0">
        <div class="col-sm p-0 m-0">
            <h3 class= "gramps-image"> Featured Destination: Brambuk (Grampians) Edible Bushfood Track <br>
    Native edible plants have fed humans for hundreds of years. On this 8km track in the heart of the Brambuk (Grampians), you can learn about the importance of Bushfood with a downloadable guide created in collaboration with Jadawadjali and Djab Wurrung peoples. </h3>
         </div> 
     </div>
```